# inflate the listview in segmented group android

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-fragments

[segmented group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GzxLV.png)

I am new in android , I want to inflate the listview in segmented group.
I want to show the record university in listview, categorize in

1. all record
2. student record
3. teacher record
4. other staff record

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As i am getting is that you want to **categorize the ListView** according to your records as you described (all, student, teacher and other).

My suggestion is to use **Expandable ListView.** 
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ExpandableListView.html

You can categorize your records in expandable Listview very efficiently.

Also can customize it according to yourself. Like collapsing and expanding a particular record or expand all records by default.